# In linux shell, how to copy all files/subdirs into subdir, except the subdir itself?

Tags: shell

Say I have this directory structure

```
/path/topdir
/path/topdir/subdir1
/path/topdir/subdir2
/path/topdir/subdir3
/path/topdir/file1.txt
/path/topdir/file2.txt
/path/topdir/file3.txt
```

What's a 1-liner shell command (not awk nor perl, etc., strictly shell) to copy everything in `topdir` into `subdir3`, except `subdir3` itself?

Answer (score 1):

In Linux

```
$ cp -r !(subdir3) subdir3
```

On Mac OS

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ cp -r !(subdir3) subdir3
```